# images in table with no border at all? how? width and height issues.. in css / html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table with only images in the table without any sort of padding or border (totally seamless) and can get vertical with no border/padding/spacing at all… however, the horizontal: there are gaps and spaces… no matter what I try… sorry I couldn't find an answer regarding this. Excuse the messy code, please!

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table.a {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-right: 100%;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

td {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0px;
}

tr.spaceUnder>td {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="a">
  <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td>
      <a href="/"><img src="mcu.jpg" alt="info"></a>
    </td>
    <td><img src="fill1.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td><img src="fill2.jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="mcu41.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td><img src="fill3.jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="news.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use border and padding in `td` to get border and spacing

```
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333;
}
```

For Bootstrap add class for table `table-bordered`

```
<table class="table-bordered"></div>
```

Comment: i don't want any border of any kind tho. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have already set the height and width of `a` class element of `table` class
Change the `width` and `height` to `auto`:

```
  table.a {
      table-layout: auto;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: 100%;
      margin-left: 0%;
    }
```

check :
https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/q8m1n57h/1/